# SharePoint Online authentication through javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, sharepoint

I am trying to authenticate to SharePoint Online using the following snippet of code:

http://woodoweb.com/remote-authentication-to-sharepoint-online-using-javascript/

The problem is that if I use a Active Directory user, I get back the following error during authentication:

Direct login to WLID is not allowed for this federated namespace

If I user a non-AD user, everything works fine.

I have tried doing a Google search and am unable to find anything useful. One unrelated link that I found is this:

http://sourceforge.net/p/sipe/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#login-to-my-microsoft-office365-account-is-rejected-with-direct-login-to-wlid-is-not-allowed-for-this-federated-namespace

But I am not sure how that helps me solve my issue.

Can someone please provide some help?